# How to understand this Java 8 Stream collect() method?

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8, java-stream

I was trying to convert an int array to List and I took the unfamiliar route of using Java 8 Stream and came up with this

```
Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I still have difficulty fully understand this line, mostly,

1. Why is `Collectors.toList()` in this case returns an `ArrayList<Integer>` implementing `List` interface? Why not `LinkedList<Integer>` or any other generic class conforming to `List` interface? I can't find anything about this, except for a brief mentioning of ArrayList [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-), in the API Notes section.
2. What does the left panel of 
   [image] `Stream.collect()` mean? Obviously `R` is the generic return type (`ArrayList<Integer>` in my code here). And I think `<R, A>` is the generic type argument of the method, but how are they specified? I looked into [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) interface doc and was not able to absorb it.

Comment: 1. It does use an actual list under the hood, obviously. But it would be unwise for an API to reveal the actual underlying List type. Since then they could never change the implementation anymore in the future. In general, it is often a good idea to only expose interfaces and never the actual underlying type.
2. `R` is the generic type of the resulting type. `A` the generic type of the intermediate accumulation type of the Collector. That is implementation detail of how a collector works.It does divide and conquer, also for parallel processing, collects first into intermediate types.

Comment: You almost never *actually* want LinkedList. [There is a tweet by Josh Bloch](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248?s=09), saying "I wrote it, and I never use it".

Comment: *"Why is `Collectors.toList()` in this case returns an `ArrayList<Integer>`"* It might not return an `ArrayList`. The `List` implementation is **undefined**, so you cannot rely on what implementation it returns. As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) says: *"There are **no guarantees on the type**, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned;"*

Comment: and `toList()` is not returning an `ArrayList` or `List` - it is returning a `Collector`, which will eventually create and return a `List` - also the documentation states: "...There are no guarantees on **the type**, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; **if more control over the returned List is required, use toCollection(Supplier)**...."

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger You are right sir. I should have said, the `R` part of the Collectors.toList() return is ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: I strongly recommend [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. It's a default implementation. `ArrayList` is used, because it's best in most use cases, but if it's not suitable for you, you can always define your own collector and provide factory for `Collection` you wish:

   ```
   Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(toCollection(LinkedList::new));
   ```
2. Yes, `A` and `R` are generic parameters of this method, `R` is the return type, `T` is the input type and `A` is an intermediate type, that appears in the whole process of collecting elements (might not be visible and does not concern this function). [The beginning of `Collector`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) defines those types (they are consistent across the entire doc):

   > T - the type of input elements to the reduction operation
   >   A - the mutable accumulation type of the reduction operation (often hidden as an implementation detail)
   >   R - the result type of the reduction operation

Comment: Ok I see. I guess I should really stick to `List<Integer> myList = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());` and call only methods declared in List interface upon myList. Otherwise I'd potentially be putting myself in risk, if Oracle decides to change the default implementation in Java8u1024 or 15?

Comment: @user3207158 the method returns a `List`, so whatever implementation is used, behavior is the same. It is unlikely the interface will be changed in newer versions of java.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Why is Collectors.toList() in this case returns an ArrayList implementing List interface?**

As the method definition suggests it returns a Collector implementation with collector supplier as `ArrayList`. Hence, it's very clear from method definition below that `Collectors.toList` always returns ArrayList collector(`While it's arguable why toList not toArrayList word is used in method name`).

```
public static <T>
    Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
        return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                                   (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                                   CH_ID);
    }
```

2. **What does the left panel of `<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)` means**

If you refer to documentation comments it accurately mentions what these generic types are:

```
/*
      @param <R> the type of the result
      @param <A> the intermediate accumulation type of the {@code Collector}
      @param collector the {@code Collector} describing the reduction
      @return the result of the reduction
*/
 <R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Where did you get the source code of `Collectors.toList()` (first snippet)? Is it openjdk?

Comment: No! I have downloaded the source code in my intelli j